# How to retrieve all posts using blogger API by using JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, json, api, google-api, blogger

I am trying To Get List of all Blog Posts Using Blogger API by using javascript Loop. I found a solution in StackOverflow too. but that didn't work for me.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function handleResponse(response) {
  var post_number  = Object.keys(response.items).length; //number of posts
  for (i=0; i<post_number; i++) {
    $('#content').append('<div id="post' + (i+1) + '" class="post"><p></p></div>');
    $('.post p').html(response.items[i].title);
  }
}
</script>
<script src="https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/5039479718685240371/posts?callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyDxfWmXTRnO5yIp25NvuUEBWKSa_5mqjHA"></script>
```

below error was occur when I run This Code:`{
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 17,
  "colno": 5
}`

Comment: perhaps you didn't include the jQuery library?

Comment: Do you have a reference to JQuery?

Comment: nah! I think It only Works with pure javascript only to reduce the load time?

Comment: $() is not pure javascript, it is jquery.

Comment: I include jquery link but it didn't work with that too

Comment: Was it a different error, or the same error?

Comment: Yeah! I include this before the code you can check it in above code I update it.

Comment: No this doesn't show any error but it didn't work

Comment: That snippet above would never work because you don't have any actual elements defined (and specifically none defined with an id of `content`).

Comment: Can you make it work for me once?

Comment: just create a div with the id "content". And after that fix `$('.post p').html(response.items[i].title);` so it doesn't update _every_ post element. You could just put the title directly into the line above, no need for this extra line anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some trial and error with your code and the first problem you noted was solved by including the jQuery library.

You can use ajax to GET the data instead of including it in a script tag. jQuery will register and call the callback function for you.

The rest worked. Here is a example. I would also suggest changing your key now.

```js
$.ajax("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/5039479718685240371/posts?callback=handleResponse&key=AIzaSyDxfWmXTRnO5yIp25NvuUEBWKSa_5mqjHA")

function handleResponse(response) {
  //var post_number = Object.keys(response.items).length; //number of posts
  for (i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
    var titleHtml = '<div id="post' + (i + 1) + '" class="post"><p>' + response.items[i].title + '</p></div>';
    $('#content').append(titleHtml);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add post content too in it?

Comment: "It had some callback logic in", that's just JSONP, surely?

Comment: that would be a totally different question and you should try to do it yourself. When you stuck and have a specific question you can come back and post it as a new question. I would suggest googling up on ajax posts

Comment: @AjayMalik just use the "content" field from the object, just like this is using the title field. If you look at the JSON, that should be obvious, no? And you maybe need to wrap it in some more HTML, but the structure of that is up to you. Do you actually understand _any_ of this code you've got? You seem to be asking for every tiny detail to be given to you 100% complete.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for specifying, I never worked with JSONP before

Comment: @AjayMalik I misunderstood your question about "post content" I thought you meant POSTing content to the API. You can access the blog content just as ADyson suggested

Comment: Don't worry! you help me to understand that messy code. it works like I want.